# Android EditText Returns Strange Output

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext

I hate asking questions unless I absolutely have to, but I can't seem to find a clear answer to this problem. 
I'm working on a practice app and one of the activities should take user input via an EditText view, and then return that input to the activity's TextView view, i.e. it should say hello back to the user after the user has typed their name in. 
Instead of returning the user input, it gives me back this strange string of characters for some reason. Here's my code for reference:

```
text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTextView);
input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mEditText);
enter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mButton);        

enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
public void onClick(View v) { text.setText("Hello " + input);       
}       
});
}
```

So rather than returning "Hello (user input)", it outputs something like:

Hello android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{3f5e428a .. So I'm confused as all hell right now.

Help!

P.S. - I would've posted screenshots but apparently I need 10 reputation points before I can do that, so hopefully this is enough..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the string value from an EditText:

```
String s = input.getText().toString()
```

You can put that into the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

`input` is an `EditText`, not the actual text thats been typed into the view.

You need to call `input.getText()` to get the text in it.

The value that you are getting is the default behavior of `toString` on the EditText.